# How to set Caretposition via mouse click in content editable within a draggable in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, draggable, contenteditable, caret

Aparrently Firefox has issues when trying to click into a string within a contenteditable dom element, if the dom element is within a `draggable="true"` dom element.

Is this a general Firefox issue? Any Ideas on how to circumvent it?

Here is a fiddle which works in firefox and chrome
https://jsfiddle.net/yam9kkbL/

and here is a fiddle having a draggable as the parent which works in chrome but not in Firefox
https://jsfiddle.net/msw26kf0/

In firefox my click on whatever char in the string of the contenteditable element sets my pointer before the first char of the string.

Tried my own code in chrome and it works as expected. Tried the same code in Firefox and it did not work. Created a fiddle with an isolated example using just html5 instead of my vue3 templates and saw that it also did not work there so my own code seems not to be the root cause of the issue

edit: Filed a bug report at mozilla
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1881528